# How to create user interface for rest api using spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient-interceptors, admin-interface

I have created a Rest API using springBoot and using Postman for creating GET, POST, PUT ,Delete Requests.
To display data to enduser i am using Angular .
My Application is Read only for enduser , and hence i am calling only Get Requests from my Angular code.

I need to create user friendly interface for admin, to input data using forms and suitable options.

Should i create another angular application for admin, or is it possible using springboot also,

I am also wondering if i will be able to Live my Client as well as Admin application on Same url or i would have to buy 2 url , one for client and one for admin.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, since you already have an Angular front-end UI, you can just add role based logins and provide them with different options to play with.

Like you can assign all the users registering from ui as `ROLE_USER` and there would be one admin account(this you can create implicitly from within the boot app) with role `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Now having done this, you need to apply spring-security with basic-auth and role-based login. On successful authentication, check their roles and redirect them to different controller methods which will eventually render different pages.

This is what I hope would be the naive approach for a basic flow. Cheers :)

Comment: If your answer starts with _"In my opinion"_ the question is opinion based and should be closed

Comment: Sir but i do not want to show login button on my website for end user,  then can you please guide me how can i do it

Comment: I guess I do not understand your use case, try elaborating(editing) you question with some flow